# Displaying an external webpage in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm not understanding Sharepoint 2010. I have an external webpage which I want to display inside of Sharepoint 2010.  I have used a Content Editor and a Media Web Part both give the same results.  Obviously, it's not taking the CSS into account.  How do I fix this?  Also, I've tried this in Office 365 and it does display correctly.

Supposed to Look like
[image: Supposed To look like]

Actually Looks like
[image: ActuallyTo look like]

Comment: can you check the console? Is there any error?

Comment: Seems like the SharePoint css is taking over the page. what is the purpose of linking to this inside SharePoint instead of a simple redirect?

Comment: @Atish I'm not a sharepoint person by any stretch of the imagination.  When you say "console" what are you referring to?

Comment: @Mike. I don't like the idea either but it's was a requirement from the business people and the project manager.  If its not going to be an easy task, I can push back.

Comment: Businessmen and project managers aren't experts, so I'd give an alternative solution to what they are after. That's just my opinion. Referencing a whole external page in SharePoint is very clunky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better try the "Page viewer" Web part, witch is actually an iFrame, letting you point to any external Web page you want (you only need to set its URL in the Web part settings).